# firefox not showing whole download name and extension

Tags: php, firefox, download, filenames

Ive got a php download script using mod_xsendfile which works perfectly to download certian rar files.

In Chrome and IE it downloads fine, I get the filenames like "0005 - Game Name.rar"

In firefox it always just downloads a file with the name a couple of characters long like "0005 -" it never has the extension so a user might not understand how to rename.

Is there somthing i can change in my script to allow firefox to read the whole filename.

Here is the part of the script that handles the downloading.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
header("X-Sendfile: $file");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe I've had this issue once. I think `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");` (quoting the filename) did the trick for firefox. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote the filename:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
```

Comment: I was using single quotes, but it seems that the double quotes are required.